# VS Code command "code -v" doesn't work as expected

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, command-line-interface

When I launch the "**code**" command (VS Code) **with optional arguments** (CLI options),
from Cmd (or any other CLI) it opens VS Code instead of giving me the awaited result.

For ex. if I type "**code -v**", or "**code --version**", *instead of telling me the version, **it opens VS Code***.
Same if I type "**code -h**" or "**code --help**".
(Appart from that, everything is working fine, for ex. if I type "code .", or "code bogus.txt".)

I am on Windows 10, with Vs Code installed in portable mode.
Of course the directory in which I installed Vs Code is in my Path environment variable.

I resarched some answers but couldn't find anybody that documented the same problem I am facing.

Comment: I'm only using the normal install (not portable) and the 4 commands work both under cmd and PowerShell. As suggested by @myf try adding the executable to your path as well as the parent folder. Otherwise... you can use the old fashion IT magic trick... reinstall and reboot ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most probably calling something like

```
(wrong)
C:\apps\VSCode\code --version
```

what does not work.

Make sure that **VSC executable in your `path` is from the `/bin/` folder**, not its parent, i.e.:

```
where code
```

returns something like

```
C:\apps\VSCode\bin\code
C:\apps\VSCode\bin\code.cmd
```

You can verify that before altering your `path` environment variable by calling

```
(correct)
C:\apps\VSCode\bin\code --version
```